# Serialization and Deserialization of Complex objects using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am facing an issue with using Converters of JSON.NET with ASP.NET WebApi. Here is the representation of the scenario

An Attribute class could be of type Parent or Measurement with their serialization nature of the properties mentioned.

```
[DataContract]
[JsonConverter(typeof(AttributeConverter))]    
public abstract class Attribute
{

    [DataMember] public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string DisplayLabel { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Parent : Attribute
{
    [DataMember] public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Measurement : Attribute
{
    [DataMember] public Bound Bounds { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int measurementValue { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want the default "$type" attributes which gets injected during serialization for handling types by Json.NET and hence have set the following properties in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =` Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

As per our requirement, I need an identifier to specify the kind of an Attribute which is the same thing that "$type" provides. We have written a custom converter that will introduce the AttributeKind information during Serialization and is recovered during deserialization using ReadJson() of my converter. The code snippet is shown below

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
   writer.WriteStartObject();
   writer.WritePropertyName("AttributeKind");

   AttributeKind type = (AttributeKind)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(AttributeKind), value.GetType().Name);
   writer.WriteValue(type);

   var props = value.GetType().GetProperties();
   foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
   {
       var tempVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(value, null);
       if (tempVal == null) continue;

       writer.WritePropertyName(propertyInfo.Name);
       serializer.Serialize(writer, tempVal);
    }
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject jObject = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);

    JProperty jProperty = jObject.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "AttributeKind");

    if (jProperty == null)
        return null;

    JValue value = jProperty.Value as JValue;

    AttributeKind attributeKind = (AttributeKind)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(AttributeKind), value.Value.ToString());

    Attribute attribute = null;
    switch (attributeKind)
    {
        case AttributeKind.ParentAttribute:
            attribute = new ParentAttribute();
            break;

        case AttributeKind.MeasurementAttribute:
            attribute = new MeasurementAttribute();
            break;
    }

    var props = attribute.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        jProperty = jObject.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyInfo.Name);
        if (jProperty != null)
        {
            JValue jValue = jProperty.Value as JValue;

            if (jValue != null)
            {
                object dataValue = null;
                if (jValue.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
                    dataValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(jValue.Value);
                else
                    dataValue = jValue.Value;

                propertyInfo.SetValue(attribute, dataValue, null);
            }
        }
    }
    return attribute;
}
```

Following are the issues that were observed in the deserialized response:

1. An empty attribute list incase of ParentType attribute where the serialized input has elements.
2. The Bounds property has not been populated and returns null.

I am not able to move forward as I don't seems to have a complete understanding on how JsonConverters gets intercepted  and how the interception happens incase if there is a chaining of converters (i.e., 2 converters.. one for Class and another one for a complex property)

Any help is much appreciated? Thanks